# TF2.6: ValueError: Model cannot be saved because the input shapes have not been set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, subclassing

I want to create a custom model using transfer learning in Google Colab.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.xception import Xception

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes=5, dropout_rate=0.5):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.weight_dict = {}
    self.weight_dict['backbone'] = Xception(input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    self.weight_dict['outputs'] = Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), padding="same", activation="softmax")
    self.build((None,) + input_shape)

  def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    self.weight_dict['backbone'].trainable = False
    x = self.weight_dict['backbone'](inputs)
    x = self.weight_dict['outputs'](x)
    return x

model = MyModel(input_shape=(256, 256, 3))
model.save('./saved')
```

However, I encounter this error:

```
ValueError: Model `<__main__.MyModel object at 0x7fc66134bdd0>` cannot be saved because the input shapes have not been set. Usually, input shapes are automatically determined from calling `.fit()` or `.predict()`. To manually set the shapes, call `model.build(input_shape)`.
```

Yes, there is no call to `.fit()` or `.predict()`. But there is a call to `.build` in the `__init__()` method of the class. What am I to do?

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31057#issuecomment-616804834), [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39906#issuecomment-750841973)?

Comment: @TFer2 Thank you very, much! The second link did it for me! If you want, post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: That's good to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the layer has not been built, [compute_output_shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#compute_output_shape) will call build on the layer. This assumes that the layer will later be used with inputs that match the input shape provided.

Working code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications.xception import Xception

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes=5, dropout_rate=0.5):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.weight_dict = {}
    self.weight_dict['backbone'] = Xception(input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    self.weight_dict['outputs'] = Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), padding="same", activation="softmax")
    self.build((None,) + input_shape)

  def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    self.weight_dict['backbone'].trainable = False
    x = self.weight_dict['backbone'](inputs)
    x = self.weight_dict['outputs'](x)
    return x

input_shape=(256, 256, 3)
model=MyModel(input_shape)

model.compute_output_shape(input_shape=(None, 256, 256, 3))
model.save('./saved')
```

Output:

```
2.6.0

Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/xception/xception_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
83689472/83683744 [==============================] - 1s 0us/step
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: ./saved/assets
```

For more information you can refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39906).

Answer (score 0):

If you build e.g. a GNN with multiple inputs of variable size, the proposal of TFer2 won't work. Specifying the TensorSpecs in the decorator AND using `tf.saved_model.save` instead works:

```
import keras.layers
import tensorflow as tf
import unittest


class TestModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestModel, self).__init__()
        self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.initializers.he_normal()(shape=[10, 10]))

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([10, None], tf.float32), tf.TensorSpec([10, None], tf.float32)])  # This line defines the inputs' sizes of the network call
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return tf.matmul(self.w, x) + tf.matmul(self.w, y)


class SaveAndLoadTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SaveAndLoadTest, self).__init__()

        x = tf.ones([10, 5])
        y = tf.ones([10, 5])

        model = TestModel()
        z = model(x, y)

        tf.saved_model.save(model, "/tmp/test_model/")  # saving a this way works
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            model.save("/tmp/test_model/")  # saving a model this way fails, regardless of assigning TensorSpecs to tf.function

        model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load("/tmp/test_model/")
        z_loaded = model_loaded(x, y)

        self.assertTrue((z_loaded.numpy() == z.numpy()).all())  # making sure the outputs are the same


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SaveAndLoadTest()
    print("Success.")
```